# Convert datetime in Python list to year only

Tags: python, pyodbc

So I'm using pyodbc to take a Date Time field from MS Access add to a Python list.  When I do this, it pyodbc instantly converts the data to this format `datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1,0,0)`.   I'm only interested in obtaining the year `2012` in this case.  How can I parse the year out of my List when it uses this format?  Maybe pyodbc has some syntax I could use before it evens gets into the List?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
>>> dt = datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1,0,0)
>>> dt.year
2012
```

Just for the record, `datetime.datetime` is not a "list of values", it's a class.

Comment: Cool, didn't realize it was that simple.  I can simply add '.year' the end of row.Date, so it's like this now row.Date.year with 'Date' being the table's field name that has the datetime type.  Thanks, I mark this as the answer.

Comment: A lot of documentation is stored with the classes and functions in python. Try `dir(datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1,0,0))` to see members and `help(datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1,0,0))` to see all the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the year from each of the datetime objects and form a new list.

```
years = [x.year for x in your_list]
```